# Why is Firefox missing the border on some HTML tables

Tags: html, firefox, html-table, border

I am using Firefox 3.5.7 and I have the same CSS used in multiple HTML tables, but there are some examples where parts of the borders are not shown.

What makes no sense to me is that the same CSS on the same page for another HTML table works fine. Also, the same page in Internet Explorer looks fine from a border point of view.

Here is an image with an example, as you can see in this case the bottom of the first table is missing a border.

[image]

Does anyone have a clue why this would happen here?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Maybe you've zoomed in/out a bit. This can happen either accidently or knowingly when you do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Scrollwheel. Maybe it isn't completely resetted to zoom level zero. This mis-rendering behaviour is then recognizeable at some websites, also here at SO.

To fix this, just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> or do *View* > *Zoom* > *Reset* to reset the zoom level to default.

This is Firefox/Gecko bug [410959](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=410959). This affects tables with `border-collapse:collapse`. It's from 2008 and there's no real progress on it, so you'll probably need to find a workaround. One way is using `border-collapse:separate` and fiddling with borders on a per-cell basis.

Comment: you are right . . that works.  but i still dont get it . .why would zooming remove some borders but not others ??

Comment: It's hard to halven the thickness of a one-pixel thick line. As said, it's just a mis-rendering behaviour.

Comment: As an example, try to zoom out the SO page you're facing now. You'll see that the tabs `oldest`, `newest` and/or `votes` here above will virtually lose their border-bottom at certain levels.

Comment: interesting . . i guess it makes sense . .but i would still expect it to be consistent across the same size element.. so i would expect every table to lose its border consistently

Comment: No, surely not. If you shrink from e.g. 800px height to 799px height, then there's still only 1px line which can be dropped.

Comment: Ctrl+0 is more of a user-side fix, and a pretty poor one at that... The [work-around posted by GregL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4731524/33080) does the job while allowing users to zoom freely. Supporting zoom is not really optional anymore, seeing as high DPI monitors are equivalent to zoom.

Comment: The bug seems to be expose also when you change your DPI setting to e.g. 125% and in Firefox the zoom to 100%

Comment: This is brillient. This has been bugging me for a while. Borders were showing one computer and not on another, and the zoom issue solved it. I didn't even know I had zoom turned on.

Comment: I am getting this bug, and the entire right border is not rendering.  I can set a THICK border, like 14 pixels on `td`, and I can see all borders, but the right border is missing.  And a thick border missing is very visible, like taking a part of a picture frame off.  So far nothing I have done, fixed the problem :(

Answer (score 11):

I found a similar problem when zoomed out in Firefox on an application I am working on.

The main cause was having the CSS `border-collapse` property set to `collapse`.

Changing it to `separate` instead fixed the problem. However, that meant I did have to rethink the way borders are applied to various parts of the table, because otherwise your borders will appear to double in thickness. I ended up having to use jQuery to give a special "last" class to the last `td` or `th` in each `tr`, and to the last `tr` in the table. My query was something like:

```
$('table tr > th:last-child, table > tbody > tr > td:last-child, table > tbody > tr:last-child').addClass('last');
```

My CSS rules were similar that:

```
table
{
    border-collapse: separate !important;
}

table tr, table th, table td
{
    border-right-width: 0;
    border-bottom-width: 0;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}

table td.last, table th.last 
{
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

table tr.last td
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

table
{
    border: 0;
}
```

I did end up using browser targeting so that I only applied these rules to Firefox users, but it may work for all browsers, I haven't tested.

Comment: just to be fair, this issue is not "caused" by  border-collapse, it's caused by a [firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=410959) that's been reported ten years ago (pending fix, as with many old reported firefox bugs)

Answer (score 2):

Building on the good answer of @GregL (I seem unable to "comment" directly on it):
Instead of using JQuery to generate a "last" class, I simply used the built-in pseudo-element selector `:first-child`. I built rules selecting `tr:first-child` and `td:first-child` that define `border-top` and `border-left` (instead of `border-right` and `border-bottom` as in GregL's answer). The generic rules define `border-right` and `border-bottom` instead of `border-left` and `border-top`. `:first-child` is [said to be supported](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp) in Chrome v. 4.0, Firefox v. 3.0, IE 7.0, Safari v. 3.1, and Opera v. 9.6 (). Tested on Firefox v. 40.0.3, where I saw this problem in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by the table (with a missing bottom-border) to be inside a div...The border apparently didn't get calculated in the table height, so the border was there but wasn't shown.

Giving the surrounding div a margin-bottom from 1px solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `border-spacing:0;` hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Border started going missing when browser zoom was increased. I was able to solve it by doing the following. Tested in Chrome and Firefox.

```
padding: 0.5px !important
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with missing table border.
My solution is:

```
table{
  border-collapse: collapse !important;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
}
```

And border for table rows:

```
table tr{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD !important;
}
```

*I am using Bootstrap either in my layout and the table has also bootstrap css classes like "table table-striped table-bordered"*

This solution works for me, when I tried solution with

```
border-collapse: separate !important;
```

it didn't work properly for me.

Answer (score 0):

worked for me realisation of answer @Donald Payne

*( .table - bootstrap class )

```
table.table {
    border-collapse: separate !important;
}

table.table tr,
table.table th,
table.table td {
    border-right-width: 0 !important;
    border-bottom-width: 0 !important;
    border-left: 1px solid #DDD !important;
    border-top: 1px solid #DDD !important;
}

table.table td:last-child,
table.table th:last-child {
    border-right: 1px solid #DDD !important;
}

table.table tr:last-child td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD !important;
}

table.table {
    border: 0 !important;
}

table.table thead tr:last-child th,
table.table thead tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD !important;
}

table.table tbody tr:first-child th,
table.table tbody tr:first-child td {
  border-top-width: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tangential, but for those searching for missing borders in Firefox…

I had a border-bottom of a table-row (`<tr>`) that was missing where a background had been set on a specific cell.  It turned out this was caused by a rogue `position: relative` on the cell, removing that (or changing it to `position: inherit`) fixed it.

*Firefox 70.0.1*