# bootstrap 3 table-bordered border issue

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Hi I try bootstrap 3 table-bordered and my right border not shown. This is my table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
...
</table>
```

And this is an image of my table. My right border is invisible like this:

[image]

And sometimes my horizontal border also invisible like this: 
[image]

This issue only appear in Firefox. Where is my borders?

Comment: It's really hard to determine without seeing any code; could you share what you have? That said, it looks like maybe the table is overflowing out of its parent, causing the border to be cut off (but without being able to check for myself, can't say for sure).

Comment: Which browser does the problem appear?

Comment: Thanks @oxguy3 I'm going to check overflowing from parent.

Comment: @SylvainMARTIN : this issue only appear in firefox

Comment: This is a bug of firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohhh, this is a small accidentally issue because of browser zoom.

I found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2061785/2232900) and this is an old Firefox bug [Table cell border widths render incorrectly at various zoom levels](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=410959).

Unfortunately, these bugs was wasted much time from me. Hoping to fix this bug in the near future.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug, you need to add the tbody

`.table-bordered` with an empty `<tbody>` is missing borders.

look at this page https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=409254

```
$('tbody').addClass('hidden');

$('button').on('click',function(){
    tr='<tr><td>td</td><td>td</td><td>td</td><td><button type="button" onclick="$(this).closest(\'tr\').remove();" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button></td></tr>';
    $('tbody').removeClass('hidden');
    $('tbody').append(tr);
});
```

Comment: I think this is not the case here. The bug you have mentioned is this ([**jsfiddle open in firefox**](http://jsfiddle.net/B3CWR/3/)).  As described in the bug report *only the top border is displayed*.